# How do I pull out the difference in both lists?

Tags: c#, .net

As you can see below I need to have an output for showing **additions**, **changes**, and **removed students**. Thought I have researched how to exactly do this and kept finding what I have setup currently in `RemovedStudents()`. Does anyone have any examples that could help me finish this up for the additions, changes and removed students methods? I would appreciate any help on this!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace OldandNewStudents
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Display lists of students
            Console.WriteLine("Here is the list of old students: ");
            ShowStudents(GetStudentsOld());
            Console.WriteLine("Here is the list of new students: ");
            ShowStudents(GetStudentsNew());

            //Show the additions
            Console.WriteLine("Here is the list Additions: ");

            //Show the changes
            Console.WriteLine("Here is the list of Changes: ");

            //Show the removed students
            Console.WriteLine("Here is the list of removed students: ");
            RemovedStudents(GetStudentsNew(), GetStudentsOld());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static List<Student> GetStudentsOld()
        {
            List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

            students.Add(new Student("111", "Michael", "Tucker", "Junior", 10));
            students.Add(new Student("222", "Svetlana", "Omelchenko", "Senior", 2));
            students.Add(new Student("333", "Michiko", "Osada", "Senior", 7));
            students.Add(new Student("444", "Hugo", "Garcia", "Junior", 16));
            students.Add(new Student("555", "Cesar", "Garcia", "Freshman", 4));
            students.Add(new Student("666", "Fadi", "Fakhouri", "Senior", 72));
            students.Add(new Student("777", "Hanying", "Feng", "Senior", 11));
            students.Add(new Student("888", "Debra", "Garcia", "Junior", 41));
            students.Add(new Student("999", "Terry", "Adams", "Senior", 6));
            students.Add(new Student("211", "Bob", "Stephenson", "Junior", 150));
            return students;
        }

        public static List<Student> GetStudentsNew()
        {
           List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

            students.Add(new Student("111", "Michael", "Tucker", "Junior", 10));
            students.Add(new Student("222", "Svetlana", "Omelchenko", "Senior", 2));
            students.Add(new Student("333", "Michiko", "Osada", "Senior", 7));
            students.Add(new Student("311", "Sven", "Mortensen", "Freshman", 53));
            students.Add(new Student("444", "Hugo", "Garcia", "Freshman", 16));
            students.Add(new Student("555", "Cesar", "Garcia", "Freshman", 4));
            students.Add(new Student("666", "Fadi", "Fakhouri", "Senior", 72));
            students.Add(new Student("777", "Hanying", "Feng", "Senior", 11));
            students.Add(new Student("888", "Debra", "Garcia", "Junior", 41));
            students.Add(new Student("411", "Lance", "Tucker", "Junior", 60));
            students.Add(new Student("999", "Terry", "Adams", "Senior", 6));
            return students;
        }

        public static void ShowStudents(List<Student> stuList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();

            foreach (Student s in stuList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        public static void RemovedStudents(List<Student> stuNewList, List<Student> stuOldList)
        {
            List<Student> removedStudents = stuNewList.Except(stuOldList).ToList();
            IEnumerable<Student> differenceQuery = stuNewList.Except(stuOldList);
            foreach (Student s in differenceQuery)
                Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my new updated RemovedStudents Method:

```
public static void RemovedStudents(List<Student> stuNewList, List<Student> stuOldList)
    {
        GetStudentsOld().Except(GetStudentsNew());
        foreach (Student s in stuNewList)
            Console.WriteLine("student: {0} {1}", s.FirstName, s.LastName);
    }
```

Here is the Student Class, though I am not allowed to edit it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace OldandNewStudents
{
public class Student
{
    // Sample Student class
    // Each student has a first name, a last name, a class year, and a rank 
    // that indicates academic ranking in the student body.

    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string StudentYear { get; set; }
    public int StudentRank { get; set; }

    public Student(string idNumber, string firstName, string lastName, string studentYear, int studentRank)
    {
        ID = idNumber;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        StudentYear = studentYear;
        StudentRank = studentRank;
    }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ID + " " + FirstName + " " + LastName + " " + StudentYear + " " + StudentRank;
    }
}
}
```

Here is my NEW addition method, but I'm not sure why I am getting an overload error:

```
public static List<Student> GetActualNewStudents(List<Student> oldStudents, List<Student> newStudents)
    {
        List<Student> actualNewStudents = new List<Student>();

        foreach (var student in oldStudents) {
            if (oldStudents[student].ID != newStudents[student].ID)
            {
                actualNewStudents.Add(newStudents[student]);
            }
        }

        return actualNewStudents;
    }
```

Comment: *Additions* is quite simply the opposite of *removals*. Changes are only changes if the student exists in both sets. At the very least, you should be able to implement the AddedStudents method with this

Comment: @Rob Yeah I realize that. But I'm not too sure how to do the changes are the added method.

Comment: Then give us your attempt. It's quite literally swapping some variable names. We're not here to do your homework for you. Show us where you get stuck and we'll help you out, but we won't do it if you just paste us the homework assignment and tell us what the teacher asked for.

Comment: @Rob obviously just told you where i am stuck but you have yet to help me lol. This is just a small part of an assignment. I have everything figured out but this. Which is why I am asking for help. I attempted the deleting method and didn't work to what i'd expect so that is my reason for posting.

Comment: Sorry - I actually misread the question, as . I thought your `AddedStudents` method was was working, and you asked simply for the `RemovedStudents` logic. Your `RemovedStudents` logic looks fine. If it's not working, you will have to look into the code of `Student`, and override `Equals` and `GetHashCode()`.

Comment: You need to add a column to table that contains date so you can indicate additions and changes.  When deleting put results in 2nd table that contains deleted rows before removing items.  Looks like a project I did in college 40 years ago in Fortran and then Pascal using punch cards.  Final code had 600 lines with more than that in the circular basket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked and got me the results I needed:

Code for additions:

```
public static List<Student> GetActualNewStudents(List<Student> oldStudents, List<Student> newStudents)
    {
        //Show the new students
        List<Student> actualNewStudents = newStudents.Where(y => !oldStudents.Any(z => z.ID == y.ID)).ToList();

        return actualNewStudents;
    }
```

Code for Removed Students:

```
public static List<Student> GetActualRemovedStudents(List<Student> oldStudents, List<Student> newStudents)
    {
        //Show the removed students
        List<Student> actualRemovedStudents = oldStudents.Where(y => !newStudents.Any(z => z.ID == y.ID)).ToList();

        return actualRemovedStudents;
    }
```

Code for Changes:

```
public static List<Student> GetActualChangedStudents(List<Student> oldStudents, List<Student> newStudents)
    {
        //Show the changes
        List<Student> actualChangedStudents = newStudents.Where(y => !oldStudents.Any(z => z.FirstName == y.FirstName && z.LastName == y.LastName && z.StudentRank == y.StudentRank && z.StudentYear == y.StudentYear)).ToList();

        return actualChangedStudents;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is create a third array with the common students, then for all the students that aren't there, consider a new student in the new students array, of course:

EDIT:

```
public static List<Student> GetActualNewStudents(List<Student> oldStudents, List<Stident> newStudents)
    {
        var actualNewStudents = new List<Student>();
        foreach (var item in newStudents)
        {
            if (!oldStudents.Contains(item))
                actualNewStudents.Add(item);

        }
        return actualNewStudents;
    }
```

Comment: This sounds correct, but it just gives me the entire list of newStudents. It doesn't make sense to me at all. Your code should work...

Comment: Do you think I need a `Contains()` method that defines what i need to check for?

Comment: How exactly are you implementing it? Is it possible that you forgot the "!" in the conditional? Edit your post with your new class so I can check it. (I forgot to type the return at the end)

Comment: I have updated the add method above. I believe that should work if i can handle the error correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: O(n^2) method. Seriously inefficient. Consider using a HashSet instead.

Comment: @Aron what method is inefficient?

Comment: @tstokes8040 specifically `List.Contains` it is O(n) and it is called n times.

Comment: @Aron Do you have an example of the HashSet you're recommending?

Comment: 1- You are not using the foreach loop properly. For your construction, would be better to set up a for loop. 2 - Focus on solving your problem. You are not in a stage to worry about efficiency, specially because no better solution was provided.

Comment: @maugusto Yeah I was playing around with that last night but not how I can get it to work with a for loop. Got an example?

Comment: @tstokes there is nothing wrong with the answer previously posted

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using the two lists you have are the comparisons, such as the Except extension method will be using the default implementation for the `IEquatable`. You have a constructor, but the class definition is not included. If the fields and properties *only* contain value types, then a byte by byte comparison is applied. If you have any reference types then you will need to override the default Equals method. If you only have value type fields, then the following code should work.

Addition:

```
GetStudentsNew().Except(GetStudentsOld());
```

Removed:

```
GetStudentsOld.Except(GetStudentsNew());
```

Difference:

```
public diff(IEnumerable<Student> new, IEnumerable<Student> old)
{
    var both = new.AddRange(old); 
    var add = both.Except(new);
    return add.Except(old);
}
```

I should note that `Console.WriteLine` will not work as you expect, as you are passing in a reference type, and not a type that will be converted to the string you expect.

Comment: Would I just do `ShowStudents(GetStudentsNew().Except(GetStudentsOld());` to print the results?

Comment: no, that would need to print the value type properies via a String.Format. such as

    Console.WriteLine("student: {0} {1}", s.FirstName, s.LastName);

Comment: Can you confirm that this RemoveStudents method is correct 

`GetStudentsNew().Except(GetStudentsOld());`
            
`foreach (Student s in stuNewList)`

`Console.WriteLine("student: {0} {1}", s.FirstName, s.LastName);`

Comment: Just run it and compare?  I am not at a computer now, but it looks correct

Comment: Looks like it just shows the new list. Doesn't show who was removed from the OLD list. The only person that should be shown is Bob (at the bottom of the old list)

Comment: That is not the complete code, you need to have an assignment. Can you put it exactly as you have it. Edit the question with it instead of comment, and I will take a look

Comment: I have updated the question with the full code of the `RemovedStudents()` Method as the other code remains the same.

Comment: Again, the write line will not show the correct output, you need to format a string with properties to know. Can you post the Students class definition as well. the Except extension will only work with the default implementation of IEquatible of the are value type fields

Comment: What output are you seeing?

Comment: Getting all of new list

Comment: Meaning what exactly?

Comment: I get everything in the new list when I should just be getting Bob because he is the only student that was removed from the old list to the new list.